# HomeAssistant - How to edit state-badge and put icon on it

Tags: yaml

Here is my card code:

```
          - type: conditional
            conditions:
              - entity: input_boolean.menu_parter
                state: "off"
            elements:
              - entity: light.sufit_salon
                style:
                  top: 65%
                  left: 52%
                  color: transparent
                  transform: scale(0.7,0.7)
                tap_action: !include FloorPlan3D/popup/swiatlo_salon405.yaml
                type: state-badge
```

where to use card-mod to change/add icon to state-badge.

```
              card_mod:
                  style: |
                    :host {
                      --card-mod-icon: mdi:bed;
                    }
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work where it seems logical. Not only can't I change the icon, but the whole card-mod doesn't work for state-badge

```
         - type: conditional
            conditions:
              - entity: input_boolean.menu_parter
                state: "off"
            elements:
              - entity: light.sufit_salon
                style:
                  top: 65%
                  left: 52%
                  color: transparent
                  transform: scale(0.7,0.7)
                card_mod:
                  style: |
                    :host {
                      --card-mod-icon: mdi:bed;
                    }
                tap_action: !include FloorPlan3D/popup/swiatlo_salon405.yaml
                type: state-badge
```